# how to add a multiline comment go gerrit review?

Tags: python, gerrit

I am trying to add a multi-line comment using the following code but this fails with error shown below, any guidance on how to fix it?

```
message = """PLEASE RESOLVE MERGE CONFLICTS
             WHAT DO I HAVE TO DO IN CASE OF MERGE CONFLICTS:
             htts://confluence.sd.company.com/display/WFI/AUTO+CHERRY-PICK
             """.replace("\n","\n\n")
code_review_minus_two_cmd = "ssh -p 29418 tech-gerrit.sd.company.com gerrit review %s --label Code-Review=-2 --message '%s'"%(propagated_gerrit_commit,message)
code_review_minus_two_cmd_output,code_review_minus_two_cmd_error = runCmd(code_review_minus_two_cmd)
```

ERROR:-

```
fatal: "RESOLVE" is not a valid patch set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems related to this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=800).

The ways I can see to resolve it from looking through the ticket are:

1. Use -m instead of --message
2. Add double quotes around the message

Sample from the review in the bug link:

```
ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit review -m '"Build Successful"'
```

Hope something here works. I don't have a gerrit account to test out against myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a json formatted message. The easiest way would be to create a file with the following content:

```
{
  "labels": {
    "Code-Review": "-2"
  }, 
  "message": "PLEASE RESOLVE MERGE CONFLICTS\nWHAT DO I HAVE TO DO IN CASE OF MERGE CONFLICTS:\nhttps://confluence.sd.company.com/display/WFI/AUTO+CHERRY-PICK"
}
```

Then run this ssh command:

```
cat filename.json | ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit review --json
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the double quotes (""") in the "message" definition aren't working as expected. Gerrit is receiving the parameter like this: --message PLEASE RESOLVE MERGE... so it's assuming that "PLEASE" is the message and "RESOLVE" is the next parameter (patchset) as defined in the [gerrit review page at the Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-review.html).

Try to use backslashes to escape the double quotes, like this:

message = "\"PLEASE RESOLVE MERGE...\""

Answer (score 0):

The following example works in bash.

`ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit review -m $'"First line\nSecond line etc."' CHANGE_ID,PATCHSET_ID/COMMIT_SHA`